# Run PHP file (URL) from batch file

Tags: php, url, batch-file, automation

I have a batch file on my computer and a PHP file on my website. I want to run the PHP file on my website whenever I run the batch file on my computer.

I found this by searching some stuff up, but it does not work:

```
php http://test.com/test.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wget for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

```
wget http://test.com/test.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the batch file run a program that can access the web

This should work:

```
start iexplore http://test.com/test.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear to me. Are you talking about a remote or a local web server? Please be more specific as to what you intent to achieve. If you want to execute a particular script using a bat file. You can simply call the script using something like

```
firefox www.myscript.com/run.php
```

But as I said , I am not clear as to what you indent to achieve , I might be wrong.